# Set and display name and email Java objects classes

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, arraylist

I have this java class assignment, it inputs crew members and display their info, I've done other similar cases, but not sure how to construct this one.
I'm to create two classes, Sailor and CrewMember that works with this main method-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SailorProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Sailor firstSailor = new Sailor("Jimmy", "jimmy@mail.com");
        Sailor secondSailor = new Sailor("Rose", "rose@mail.com");
        Sailor thirdSailor = new Sailor("James", "james@sailors.com");


        CrewMember firstCrew = new CrewMember();
        CrewMember secondCrew = new CrewMember();

        firstCrew.addCrewMember(firstSailor);
        firstCrew.addCrewMember(secondSailor);

        secondCrew.addCrewMember(thirdSailor);
        secondCrew.addCrewMember(secondSailor);

        System.out.println(" First crew \n" + firstCrew);
        System.out.println(" Second crew \n" + secondCrew);

        secondSailor.setEmail("Rose@sailors.com");
        System.out.println(" Second crew \n" + secondCrew);
    }
}
```

then prints out

```
First crew
Jimmy (jimmy@mail.com)
Rose (rose@mail.com)

Second crew
James (james@sailors.com)
Rose (rose@mail.com)

Second crew
James (james@sailors.com)
Rose (rose@sailors.com)
```

thanks!

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Have you tried creating those classes? :) With a decent IDE, your assignment would be done in 3 seconds

Comment: @Yassin I have, setters and getters are still not clear to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't exactly clear but I will make some assumptions. First, your `CrewMember` class holds sailors, so a more appropriate name would be `Crew`. The way you can implement this is with an `ArrayList<Sailor>` for example.

```
class Crew {

    private final ArrayList<Sailor> sailors = new ArrayList<>();

    //other things, like constuctor here, if needed 

    public void addCrewMember(Sailor s) { //add sailors with this
        sailors.add(s);
    }
}
```

Then your `Sailor` class is very simple.

```
class Sailor {

    private String name;
    private String email;

    public Sailor(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name; this.email = email;
    }

    //other methods, like getters here
}
```

Edit: I noticed you need to print the objects as well. For this you can use the `Object` class' `toString` method. An example for your `Sailor` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name + ", " + email;
}
```

Using `System.out.println(sailor1)` will invoke this method on `sailor1`.

Comment: thanks, I'm still not clear on the Crew class. I have to have a Crew() constructor, the add crew method and a toString.

Comment: Exactly, you should be fine with those three methods. You could initialize the sailor list in the constructor. The toString method could print out all sailors for example (I gave a toString for sailors as an example, you can use that on each sailor in the list).

Answer (score 1):

`addCrewMember()` is the key method we want to know. If you give the `Sailor` reference to the `secondCrew` class，the output will change.

```
public class Sailor {
private String name;
private String email;

public Sailor(String name, String email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}

@Override
public String toString() {return name + " " + "(" + email + ")";}
}
```

**If the CrewMember.class Like This below**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CrewMember {

private final ArrayList<Sailor> sailors = new ArrayList<>();

public void addCrewMember(Sailor s) { //add sailors with this
    sailors.add(s);
}
@Override
public String toString() { return sailors.toString(); }
}
```

**And run your main method in your question**
thr output is this:

```
 First crew 
 [Jimmy (jimmy@mail.com), Rose (rose@mail.com)]

 Second crew 
 [James (james@sailors.com), Rose (rose@mail.com)]

 Second crew 
 [James (james@sailors.com), Rose (Rose@sailors.com)]
```

Rose@sailors.com is change!  because the *ArrayList sailors* save the reference of the Rose Sailor

Comment: thanks it worked, yet rose email format doesn't change for me. Also, how do I remove the square brackets?

Comment: CrewMember.class  have toString() method,change that method you can change the output